# Closing (not killing) an Excel file automatically on schedule

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel (read-only) file that I need to close (not kill) twice a day.

I can kill the job by using taskill, but when I restart excel to display the file I get 'Document Recovery' message that takes valuable viewing from the screen.

I left a lot out of the actual process, but I hope this is enough to get my point across.

Comment: You would need to use VBA with a blank workbook to save and close the specific workbook safely.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198003/how-to-close-a-specific-workbook-from-command-line   . Then make a scheduled task of this to run the closure on schedule.

Comment: You might consider coding an excel add-in to auto open and close a workbook on a timer. This way the add-in code is always active and the workbook doesn't have to include vba.

Comment: Also see here https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-close-and-save-workbook-on-timer.1100728/ - in general this seems like a tricky thing to get done right (using task scheduler or macros) without closing all workbooks/leaving an empty workbook/trying to reopen itself/get recovery docs. Having the add-in manage things might just be the answer.

Comment: Just edited your post, but please do not “sign” your posts as if they are a formal letter. That is not the way this site works.